# Combined Gremlin query that looks up vertices and edges by some attributes or internal IDs

Tags: gremlin

I'd like to run a Gremlin query from Java that looks for nodes and edges by their internal IDs or some other attributes, which can be specified dynamically. It could also be several queries within a transaction - whichever approach is faster. I want it to work for any popular Gremlin database (TinkerPop, JanusGraph, Orient, Neptune).

I have a query that almost does what I need:

```
g.E().or(
  hasLabel('e1').has('value','abc'),
  hasLabel('e2').has('type','router')).
union(
  identity(),
  V().or(
    hasLabel('v1').has('name','john'),
    hasLabel('v2').id().is(within(123,456))))
```

The only issue with this query is that querying by edge internal ID does not work: neither `id().is('zzz')` nor `hasId('zzz')` works inside `or()` (but it works without the `or()`).

Comment: I have so far not been able to reproduce the issue. I tested using TinkerGraph and using Amazon Neptune. In both cases the query worked. Are your ID values integers or strings? For the `is()` to work that is important.

Comment: It would be good to add minimal data which can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: For strings the incantation is `id().where(eq("zzz"))`.

Comment: You actually need to be careful with that form of `where` as it will treat `zzz` as a step label. It's fine to use `is` with strings. My point was to make sure if it is a string, you test for a string and not an integer. So for example, this is perfectly valid `g.V().values('city').is('London') `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for the suggestions. I was able to get it working using "union", which works like "or":

```
g.E().union(
  hasId(within('abc','def')),
  has('e1','value','abc')).
union(
  identity(),
  V().union(
    hasId(within(123,456)),
    has('v1','name',within('john','kevin'))))
```

It looks like JanusGraph in particular had a problem with the query that I posted in the question.